# Remove previous ComboBox SelectedItem from its next appearance bind through List

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `ComboBox` and `TextBox` like

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold">Products :</TextBlock>

<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Height="30"  
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LstProducts}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Items.Product}"/>

<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold">Cost :</TextBlock>

<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="10" Height="30"></TextBox>
```

Every time I am creating these controls on my `Button` click

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="15"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" 
FontWeight="Bold" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Name="BtnAddmore">Add Rows</Button>
```

I am binding my new created `ComboBox` on the button click event like this

```
var ddlCurriency = new ComboBox
 {
     FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
     Margin = new Thickness(7),
     BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
     Name = "NewDdlCurrency" + _btncount
}; 
ddlCurriency.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Items.Product"));
```

I don't want my previous combobox selected Items to be repeated in the list.

eg.
Suppose my first Combobox contains list of Items (A,B,C,D) and I selected **'B'** and clicked **Add Rows** button.In my next combobox list I wish to get Items(A,C,D) only.

As I am using MVVM and my **LstProducts** is in my **Product** class I also tried like this to remove selected item from this list but I am also not able to get my list '**LstProducts**'

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button button = sender as Button;
   Product obj = button.DataContext as Product;
   obj.LstProducts.Remove(this.combo.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Trying to remove the Items from the Combo box But the combo box is bind with the List "LstProducts" Try to remove the Item in "LstProducts" when Selecting the Item So It will be reflected in UI. Like this

```
var Item=combobox.selectedItem as x;
if(LstProducts.Contains(Item))
LstProducts.remove(Item);
```

Here X is Your ListItems Type. And Make sure You Implemented INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Yes I tried this by using my code 
obj.LstProducts.Remove(this.combo.SelectedItem.ToString());

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra I have edited My answer try that one.

Comment: and try Page/window DataContext Instead of Buttondatacontext.